# Laravel 7: How can I check if the team has already participated

Tags: php, laravel

Good morning all,

I have a little problem if someone can help me it would be too

Here I explain to you:

I have the 3 tables:

1. posts
2. users
3. teams

users can follow the posts with a `follow` button, the goal is to simply follow the post.

But a user can create a group (team), in order to follow the post as a group; so a group can follow posts.

- that's why I have my teams table,

To make it simple, and not to confuse with a simple user; I create a group of 1 person for each user upon registration. so I can manage users as a group;

- what I want to do is to check if the `group (team)` has already
  followed the post or not: in order to display a button "no longer
  follow" instead of the button `follow`.

If anyone has any idea how I can go about checking if any of the user's groups are following the post or not

thank you in advance :-)

Comment: You could make a `povit` table to save the relation between `teams` and `posts` and have a `following` property (or any other values) on it. Then you can query from posts or user or groups directly.  

So the relation would be `teams (m) <--> (n) posts`.  

In particular of your request you could just query directly if any of the the users team(s) is already following the post.

Comment: yes I have table (participation) with team_id & post_id
But my question is how I can check if team of user has participated? how I can do that please? :D

Comment: Depends on your Models. If you use Eloquent then something like that would work: `$post->teams->whereTeams($user->teams->pluck('id'))->get()`. `whereTeams` would be the relation / scope which you can then use as condition or in SQL words it would be the `where in` condition for the teams_id of the user. It would be very helpfull if you would provide us at least Models and Datastructure. But I believe you got the Idea now and can take it into action.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to achieve it, If you would like to save state in database, create a relational table, like

```
CREATE TABLE `participation ` (
  `Post_ID ` ,
  `User_ID ` 
)
```

Then save the User_ID and Post_ID in table when click on button, in same table you can check if user is following the Post with `Post_ID`

Edit:
If you are saving user ID, You can check in database like

```
    $exist = DB:: table('participation')
            ->where('Post_ID', $Post_ID)
            ->where('User_ID', $User_ID)->exists();
    if($exist){
        // user has participated, do whatever you want
    }else{ 
        // user has not  participated
    }
```

and if You are saving team_id as you mentioned in comment, you can use join

```
$exist = DB::table('participation')
   ->where('participation.Post_ID', $Post_ID)
   ->join('users', 'users.team_id', '=', 'participation.team_id')
   ->where('users.User_ID', $User_ID)->exists();
    if($exist)){
        // user has participated, do whatever you want
    }else{ 
        // user has not participated
    }
```

Comment: yes I have table (participation) with team_id & post_id
But my question is how I can check if team of user has participated? how I can do that please? :D

Comment: I am not sure how your data is structured, but you may need join statement if you are storing by using post_id and team_id only. see my updated answer with an idea

Answer (score 0):

It's important how you structured your relations but if "user has posts" and "team has users" is the case, you can use has many through relation. Basicaly you check if a team has a post through users. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through